# Class name composition with CssModules

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

i have some react components that compose css classes, using css modules, as shown in the following example:

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./button.module.css";

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

render() {
  let cssClass = style.field;

  if (this.props.cssClass) {
    cssClass += Array.isArray(this.props.cssClass)
      ? this.props.cssClass.map((item) => " " + style[item])
      : " " + style[this.props.cssClass];
  }

  if (this.props.customCssClass) {
    cssClass += " " + this.props.customCssClass;
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={cssClass}
    >
      {this.props.text}
    </button>
  );
 }
}

export default Button;
```

In cssClass you provide a class or an array of classes defined in the child component.

In customCssClass you provide class(es) defined in the parent component or class(es) defined globally.

This is working well. But...

My goal is to create an helper function to compose classNames avoiding copy and paste this block of code inside each component

```
  let cssClass = style.field;

  if (this.props.cssClass) {
    cssClass += Array.isArray(this.props.cssClass)
      ? this.props.cssClass.map((item) => " " + style[item])
      : " " + style[this.props.cssClass];
  }

  if (this.props.customCssClass) {
    cssClass += " " + this.props.customCssClass;
  }
```

This is what i tried so far:

```
//utils.js
export const composeClass = (style, componentClass, customCssClass) => {

  let cssClass = style;

  if (componentClass) {
    cssClass += Array.isArray(componentClass)
      ? componentClass.map((item) => " " + style[item])
      : " " + style[componentClass];
  }

  if (customCssClass) {
    cssClass += " " + customCssClass;
  }

  return cssClass;
};
```

And the above Button component should became:

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./button.module.css";
import composeClass from "./utils.js"

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

render() {
  let cssClass = composeClass(style.field, this.props.cssClass, this.props.customCssClass);

  return (
    <button
      className={cssClass}
    >
      {this.props.text}
    </button>
  );
 }
}

export default Button;
```

But i can't get it work: it seems that i can't access e.g. style[item] from another file

Is there a way to solve this? Or i have to copy and paste that code inside every components?

Comment: have you checked `classnames` ? I think it might help
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: I prefer to avoid using other library if it's not the only way to accomplish this

Comment: for learning purposes, its great, but just to get the work done, i'd prefer some easy way out 

Comment: `style.field` is a string, the scoped class. If you want to access any possible item from a module you'll need to pass the whole hash map to your helper function, so `style`.

But I second the above comment, `classnames` or `clsx` packages are doing a great (and performant) job at it. And good chances are you already have one of them in your bundles anyway :)